# What is character index returning?

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing the following:

```
char character = "123c"[3]
```

When I examine `character` in the debugger, it shows the value as `99 'c'`.

Why does it behave in this way? Is the *actual* value 99 or `c`? Is there a way to drop the "99" part and have the value be simply `c`?

Comment: What do you mean "How do I get only the character c?"

Comment: You *are* only getting the character. Don't look at the debugger/immediate window, set a variable to the result and print it out.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Why was this question put on hold for that reason?  It's definitely clear what is being asked.

Comment: @rory.ap The OP didn't provide us with an actual code snippet showing what they're trying to accomplish; the provided us with a fragment of a single statement that won't even compile.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker -- The OP provided all that was necessary.  It's pretty clear what `"123c"[3]` is: it's a string being referenced as a char array at index 3, which outputs a single char.  I had no problem figuring out what was being said.  Even if it is unclear, why just close it when it can be modified slightly to clarify.  Seems like a heavy-handed reaction.  Closing as unclear should be reserved for questions that have absolutely no hope of becoming clear.  You should be more responsible with your powers to close with one vote.

Comment: @rory.ap Putting it on hold is to give the OP a chance to fix it. I note that in your argument, you still haven't fixed the issue even though it's "Clear".  If the question had no hope, it'd be deleted, not put on hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value is still just a char = `c`.  99 is just its ASCII value.  It only shows in the debugger (i.e. "Autos"/"Locals", watches, etc.).

Comment: Is it more correct to say that the debugger shows you the decoded value `99` as well as the encoded value `'c'`?

Comment: That's basically what I said.  Decoded doesn't really mean anything given the context.

Comment: This is great to know and I'm thankful for the question and answer as I had the exact same question an hour ago interrogating a e.KeyChar value form a KeyPress event.

Comment: Why doesn't this code trim that char than: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pSjuHn? Just fyi, not sure what is going on with .NETFiddle that it thinks .Length() isn't part of string.

Comment: It looks like TimeEnd() returns rather than modifying the current string.

Comment: @4thSpace -- Dude, C# is case sensitive.  It's `Length` not `length`.  Your fiddle code is using the latter.

Comment: @rory.ap OMG Dude! VS.NET has intellisense.